# Как из адаптера обратиться к View фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть `Fragment`, в котором есть `TextView`. Как из `адаптера` получить доступ к `TextView`?
При удалении категории из списка, нужно обновить цену, не знаю как обратиться к `view` из адаптера, может объяснил как-то не понятно, но приложил скрины

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
            studentList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, studentList.size());
            mItemManger.closeAllItems();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + viewHolder.categoryName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            myDb = new DBDataSource(mContext);
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
            try {
                if(type == true){
                    myDb.deleteTask(myDb.getIdOfTransaction(item.getdateToDeleteItem()), true);
                }else{
                    myDb.deleteTask(myDb.getIdOfTransaction(item.getdateToDeleteItem()), false);
                }
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG,"item.getDate() = " + DBDataSource.makeDate2(item.getDate(), true));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dbHelper.close();

        }
    });
```

Comment: а что происходит с Фрагментом? Переключается на другой, я так понимаю, по какому-то клику? Если да, клик на закрываемый фрагмент?

Comment: @BorisSafonov, в адаптере есть обработчик кнопки удаления, удаление происходит, но textview с суммой не обновляется, вопрос обновил